# MailGun attachment not showing up PHP

Tags: php, mailgun

Email shows up with no file attached. I have a text file at test/test.txt which will not attach. Here is a simple function. When used, the email shows up with no attachment:

```
function send_email_with_attachment($email,$name){
    $mgClient = new Mailgun(MAILGUN_KEY);
    $domain = "mg.example.com";

    $file = array(
        array(
            'filePath' => 'test',
            'filename' => 'test.txt'
        )
    );

    $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain,array(
        "from"    => "Company Support <support@example.com>",
        "to"      => "{$name}<{$email}>",
        "subject" => "File Attached",
        "text"    => "Here is a cool text file",
        'attachment' => json_encode($file)
    )); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use directly attachment like that:

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain,array(
        "from"    => "Company Support <support@example.com>",
        "to"      => "{$name}<{$email}>",
        "subject" => "File Attached",
        "text"    => "Here is a cool text file",
        'attachment' => [
    ['filePath'=>'/test.txt', 'filename'=>'test']
  ]
    ));
```

Try this code to from official source:

```
$mg->messages()->send('example.com', [
  'from'    => 'bob@example.com', 
  'to'      => 'sally@example.com', 
  'subject' => 'Test file path attachments', 
  'text'    => 'Test',
  'attachment' => [
    ['filePath'=>'/tmp/foo.jpg', 'filename'=>'test.jpg']
  ]
]);
```

Comment: I tried that first but I get no email and instead, get this error: `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid resource type: array in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php:116.`

Comment: Can anyone explain the filePath and filename options? In every example I've seen, filePath is a path to an **actual file** that is different from the filename. For example, if the file is located at foo/bar.txt then the filePath would be `'foo/'` and filename would be `'bar.txt`'. But the examples don't show it in that logical way. They seem to reference two files. Thoughts?

Comment: filepath is path + name of file, filename is what user will see in the email

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with the confusion on my part about how Mailgun shows their example `filePath` and `filename` variable values.

As stated above, here is one the examples from MailGun:

```
$mg->messages()->send('example.com', [
  'from'    => 'bob@example.com', 
  'to'      => 'sally@example.com', 
  'subject' => 'Test file path attachments', 
  'text'    => 'Test',
  'attachment' => [
    ['filePath'=>'/tmp/foo.jpg', 'filename'=>'test.jpg'] //what? Which file is being sent?
  ]
]);
```

There were a couple of gotcha's here for me:

1. First was that I was using a path relative to the php file and not from the root of my server.
2. The second was that I didn't understand the mailgun example. In the example, which file is being sent? For me, this example would have been clearer:

```
$mg->messages()->send('example.com', [
  'from'    => 'bob@example.com', 
  'to'      => 'sally@example.com', 
  'subject' => 'Test file path attachments', 
  'text'    => 'Test',
  'attachment' => [
    ['filePath'=>'/tmp/foo.jpg', 'filename'=>'foo.jpg'] //this is a better way to demonstrate
  ]
]);
```